# find out when a file's contents were last modified

Tags: php, filemtime

I wrote a CMS script made of many folders and files and I want to find a way to track when I last modified any of the files. I wrote a recursive directory/file check that finds the latest modified file and gives me the date and time however my issue is this: every time that I as much as copy a file to the server, or rename a file, even if I didn't make any modifications at all to any of the files, the newly copied file or renamed file now has today's date and therefore my script shows that there was a modification made today even if I haven't made changes in weeks.

How can I circumvent that?
I am using `filemtime()`

Is there a way with PHP to know when the file was ACTUALLY last modified (ie when the code in a file was worked on the last time)?
Thanks

Comment: the problem is you dont agree with the OS's definition of  modified, in such  a case you have to record that information your self

Comment: You could use an md5 hash to actually know when your file is modified.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata how would I do that? what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that you could store the md5 hash of the file anytime you check the last modified date, and cross-check this hash with the last saved hash to know if the content actually changed. You may consider changing the title of your question properly to get better answers.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata if I did what you suggest, I would have to store all the md5_file hashes of all the files, wouldn't I? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it and wanted to post the answer:

```
$test = new SplFileInfo('path/to/file');
echo  $test->getMTime();
echo date('Y-m-d',$test->getMTime());
```

The SplFileInfo::getMTime will actually return the last time a file's contents were modified as opposed to the last modification date of the file

Comment: `SPLFileInfo::getMTime()` accesses the exact same data as `filemtime()`. There's no difference.

Comment: @duskwuff I just ran some tests comparing `getMTime` and `filemtime`, I think `getMTime` is more reliable as `filemtime` can have strange behaviours on other OS, but I cannot say for certain they may have different values.

Comment: If you refer to the relevant PHP source code ([spl_directory.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/spl/spl_directory.c) vs. [filestat.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/filestat.c)), both functions call `php_stat()` and return the `FS_MTIME` field. Again, there is no difference between the two methods.

Comment: @duskwuff I would argue there is a difference because I get different results! if you, say, rename a file on the server, the FTP browser and filemtime() will return the time when you renamed the file, even if you didn't change the contents, while SPLFileInfo::getMTime() will still return the time the file's contents were last changed.

Comment: I'm quite certain that you're mistaken. The underlying implementations of the two functions are identical. They cannot possibly return different results.

Comment: @duskwuff I am here to learn and if you can teach me that I am wrong I accept it, I'm not trying to argue with you ;-) all I can tell you is this: it is now 3pm in NYC. The last modification I made to my files was at 1.27pm. If I now (at 3pm) rename a file on the server with filemtime() I get a result of 3pm but with getMTime() I get the result of 1.27pm